# addEventListener in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, addeventlistener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [jQuery equivalent of JavaScript's addEventListener method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398099/jquery-equivalent-of-javascripts-addeventlistener-method)

Also from a very good jQuery tutorial on : http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/designmobileweb/id486198804?mt=8

What is the jQuery equivalent for the following statement;

```
element1.addEventListener('click',doSomething2,false)
```

If it is the `bind()` method, is there any option to specify the last parameter (i.e. event bubbling or capturing ... true/false)

Comment: Yes, the 3rd parameter to `bind` can still be used to that effect: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: `false` is the default for all event handlers as IE does not support triggering the handler in the capturing phase. There is no way with jQuery to set it to `true`.

Comment: @James: I think you misunderstood the third parameter. It is either a function or `false`, but `false` in this case means: *Setting the third argument to false will attach a function that prevents the default action from occurring and stops the event from bubbling.*.

Comment: @Felix - "Setting the third argument to false will attach a function that prevents the default action from occurring and stops the event from bubbling." Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Same kind of questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398099/jquery-equivalent-of-javascripts-addeventlistener-method

Comment: @James: Passing `false` to `addEventListener` does not prevent the event from bubbling. It indicates in which *phase* the event handler is to be triggered. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: @Felix - Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
// Setting the third argument to false will attach a function
// that prevents the default action from occurring and 
// stops the event from bubbling.
$("#element1").bind("click", doSomething2, false);
```

Comment: True, it's worth mentioning that it was added only since 1.4.3 version

Comment: That is not the equivalent of the `addEventListener`'s third parameter. It is merely a shortcut for `function(){ return false; }`. The call as you wrote it will treat `doSomething2` as event data (and probably throw an error).

Comment: @Felix - I agree with you but the OP wanted something like this to prevent the event bubbling by passing a parameter.

Comment: @Shankar: No, passing `false` to `addEventListener` does not do that (prevent bubbling). It just indicates in which *phase* the event handler should be triggered. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: @Felix - I am not saying that the solution which I provided is exactly equivalent to it. But it solves what OP mentioned in the second line of the question along with binding.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: What exactly does it solve? Definitely not  *event bubbling or capturing*...

Comment: @Felix - Passing `false` as 3rd parameter to [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method will attach a function that prevents the default action from occurring and stops the event from bubbling.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: Yes. But that is not what the OP is talking about (where is it written that the event should be stopped?). He does not want to *stop* bubbling, he wanted to specify whether the handler is triggered in the capturing phase or in the bubbling phase. And that is not possible with jQuery.

Comment: @Felix - May be then I have misunderstood that part of the question, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I'm pretty certain .bind() will work as you need it. Check out the [jQuery .bind() docs page](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) I'm sure you can figure out the setup. Demo code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element1").bind('click', function() {
        // do something on click
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquerys [bind method](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

example:

```
document.bind("custom-listener", someCustomFunction, false);

document.trigger("custom-listener", {jsonArgsKey:jsonValue});

function someCustomFunction(json)
{
alert(json.jsonArgsKey);
}
```

Comment: You forgot your `$` function! Don't you mean `$(document).bind...` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$(element1).click(doSomething)
```

If you want to stop bubbling, call `event.stopPropagation()` in your `doSomething` function, like this:

```
function doSomething (event){
  event.stopPropagation()
  // do whatever
}
```

There's no way to set up a capturing event handler with jQuery, though.