# Chrome extension cant run a fetch request because it violets CSP

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I am working on a chrome extension and it does work locally but it gives the following error when launched as a chrome extension:

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

my manifest file is:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Fake News Launcher",
  "description": "Check the integrity of news!",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

I tried adding "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'" but that did not fix the issue

the function that causes the error is

```
async function onTestChange() {
  let key = window.event.keyCode;
  let string = $(".fact-input").val();
  //! If the user has pressed enter
  if (key === 13) {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/create/", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          string,
        }),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      loadingbar(parseInput(data));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to enable inline execution why don't you just move your code into a .js file?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova it is inside a .js file that's the problem, on fetch API call it gives this error.

Comment: It asks you to use unsafe-inline, which suggests there is some in-line code. Can you provide an example of your code?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova added

Comment: Is this function in the background script? Where is called from?

Answer (score 0):

> Refused to execute **inline event handler** because...

it means you use inline event handlers in the tags like: `<tag onclick='some_js_code'>`,  `<select onchange='js_funct()'`, `<body onload='some_handler()'>` etc.
All these requires `'unsafe-inline'` in `script-src` (there is not any workaround using `'unsafe-hashes'` and `'hash-value'` tokens with cross browser support for now).

Best way to avoid this error and not to use `'unsafe-inline'` is to hang event handlers via [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Since you do use jQuery it's [very easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025437/addeventlistener-in-jquery).

PS: You did not shown full CSP, but the `fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/create/"` requires `connect-src 'self' http://127.0.0.1:5000` in Dev and  `connect-src 'self'` in Prod.