# Data clone error with Tesseract JS on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, tesseract.js

I am using Tesseract Js OCR, Referring [tesseract.js](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js?files=1#local-installation)
In that [local-installation approach](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js?files=1#local-installation)

Below is my Code

```
<script src="~/Scripts/tessaract.js"></script>
TesseractObj = Tesseract.create({
                workerPath: 'http://localhost:14180/scripts/worker.js',
                langPath: 'http://localhost:14180/scripts/',
                corePath: 'http://localhost:14180/scripts/index.js',
            });


TesseractObj.recognize(file)
            .progress(function (p) { console.log(p); })
            .then(function (result) {
              // my remaining code on result }
            });
```

All required js and eng.traineddata.gz files I have downloaded and referring from my solution

On Chrome browser it processing correclty but 
On Internet Explorer 11 it is throwing below **DataCloneError** 
[image: IE data clone error]

In worker.js file when **postMessage** function is called then getting this error on IE 11

```
global.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    var packet = e.data;
    workerUtils.dispatchHandlers(packet, function (obj) {
        return postMessage(obj);
    });
});
```

***Note: When I was referring cdn file then working on IE browser***

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might try taking a look here as there seems to be an issue in IE11 with postMessage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070553/postmessage-still-broken-on-ie11

Comment: Do you have a local web server?