# Find out which frame in DOM initiated a postMessage (in IE11)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

In JavaScript, once I've received a 'message' event, is there a way to find out which frame in the DOM model has initiated it? This would be helpful when debugging a large web application where a particular message could have come anyone of 15-20 frames. The message event has a source property, but if the frame is cross-domain, it's not accessible:

[image]

Since I know these things vary from browser to browser, I'm asking specifically about IE11.

Comment: Is IE 11 still legal nowadays?

Comment: Will this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070553/postmessage-still-broken-on-ie11

Comment: No, I'm well aware of that question, but what I want is to find out the identity of the frame which sent out a given message. Well, tbh I would prefer, when I have a breakpoint in a message handler, to be able to jump to the line of code which issued the postMessage() which caused this event, but even the identity of the frame would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that actually works even when cross-domain - I add a DOM element by evaluating it in the Add Watch window. Then I search the DOM tree for that element, and figure out the frame in this way.

For example, this code works:

```
var foo_btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); var foo_t = document.createTextNode("FOOBAR FOOBAR"); foo_btn.appendChild(foo_t); document.body.appendChild(foo_btn);
```

You just click Add Watch and paste it, and then after it executes, you can search for `FOOBAR FOOBAR` in the DOM tree.

[image]