# Client-to-Client CORS messaging in IE. window.postMessage()?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-domain, postmessage

Got a super annoying problem with IE10+. Window.PostMessage would not work in IE unless I ran my application in an iframe. But if I could I would use jQuery Window plugin instead.

Basically I have CMS and an APP.

In basic terms CMS triggers for the APP to open in a new browser window `window.open()`.

After all set and done on APP side I am able to fire `window.postMessage()` to my CMS that triggers UI update. Works perfect in normal browsers but doesn't work in IE.

Someone suggested to use `document.domain` to workaround the problem but that didn't help with IE problem.

Someone suggested to try `XMLHttpRequest` but thats just cross-origin ajax i.e. client-to-server request.

Running the APP in a `frame` or `iframe` is out of the question (breaks authentication).

Anyone got other suggestions on this topic?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187139/postmessage-between-cross-domain-windows-not-working-in-ie10-it-works-for-frame

Comment: Yep, I know. But if I could use an ``iframe`` I would stick with jQuery Window plugin.