# Add an event listener in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to write the following js code as jQuery:

JS

```
  document.getElementById("aa").addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler); 

  function pasteHandler(e){.....}
```

I tried something like that, but it did not work:

jQuery

```
$("#aa").addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler); 

  function pasteHandler(e){.....}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398099/jquery-equivalent-of-javascripts-addeventlistener-method

Comment: What is wrong with jQuery DOC?!...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `on`:

```
$("#aa").on("paste", pasteHandler);
```

> #### [`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)
>
> Description: *Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.*

Also, you can access the DOM element using `$("#aa")[0]` and then:

```
$("#aa")[0].addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler);
```

But that's useless because you can use the built-in jQuery method.