# TypeError: elem.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

At some place I have a code `elem.addEventListener(event, listener, false);`

The above code works for

```
this.buttonBar = doc.getElementsByClassName("wmd-button-bar" + postfix)[0]
```

But when I change to

```
this.buttonBar = $('.wmd-button-bar').first();
```

It does not work. In whole html code I have only one `wmd-button-bar` class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery equivalent of JavaScript's addEventListener method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398099/jquery-equivalent-of-javascripts-addeventlistener-method)

Comment: Your second example is a jQuery object, not a native DOM element object. `addEventListener()` is not a method of jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not working is because `$('.wmd-button-bar').first();` (which equals to `$('.wmd-button-bar').eq(0)`) returns the first *jQuery wrapped* instance.

Therefore you should use jQuery's own API for adding the listener.

However, if you want to receive a first DOM element from collection, you should use

`$('.wmd-button-bar').get(0);`

This will return first element from the jQuery wrapped collection as a DOM element.